# Is there any way to pass v-chip-group v-model id not index of item?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

https://codepen.io/xnkka/pen/GRZrQmV?editors=1010 - In this example, I have three categories with tags, one of them: "All" - contains all tags from another categories, so I want to synchronize choosing tags between categories.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    selectedTagsOrder:[],
    panel: 0,})
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
:value="tag.id"
```

on your chip to indicate the v-chip-group's v-model to use the tag's id as reference